# How to trigger PHP mail function in the background

Tags: php, email

My ISP has limited sending e-mails to 25 / 5 minutes.
I have PHP script which I access by going to a specific URL on my domain that triggers the sending of a personalized e-mail to each and every recipient that is stored in a database.

How do I enable that the script is trigger in the background and do not timeout my webpage if I add a 5 minute pause (sleep) to the script after 25 e-mails?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) or other queue server witch work with [AMQP-protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Message_Queuing_Protocol)

Comment: SplQueue will not be useful in this case as it's not a job queue, simply an implementation of the queue data structure for PHP.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a linux based host, I would use cron jobs.
They are somewhat like a scheduler which you can say "run the script in xxx/xxx.php every x number of minutes".

A format is similar to the below for cron jobs.

```
0 0 * * * php /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/scripts/example.php
```

Comment: if that's the case then unfortunately I don't see any other viable method of automating this. A suggested method would be to refresh the page every 25 minutes through javascript or php headers. But I am not too sure on how practical this would be for you since it requires the web page open the entire time.

Comment: That was what I feared.